# Getting "java.net.SocketException: Permission denied: connect" in JDeveloper

Tags: java, oracle, sockets, jdeveloper, oaf

I am getting "java.net.SocketException: Permission denied: connect" in JDeveloper.Below is the error log file:

```
18/07/22 10:40:01 java.net.SocketException: Permission denied: connect
18/07/22 10:40:01   at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
18/07/22 10:40:01   at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.doConnect(PlainSocketImpl.java:333)
18/07/22 10:40:01   at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(PlainSocketImpl.java:195)
18/07/22 10:40:01   at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:182)
18/07/22 10:40:01   at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:364)
18/07/22 10:40:01   at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:507)
18/07/22 10:40:01   at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:457)
18/07/22 10:40:01   at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:365)
18/07/22 10:40:01   at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:207)
18/07/22 10:40:01   at oracle.jdevimpl.runner.oc4j.Oc4jNotifier.sendMessage(Oc4jNotifier.java:98)
18/07/22 10:40:01   at oracle.jdevimpl.runner.oc4j.Oc4jNotifier.postInitApplicationServer(Oc4jNotifier.java:55)
18/07/22 10:40:01   at com.evermind.server.ApplicationServer.serverExtensionPostInit(ApplicationServer.java:1202)
18/07/22 10:40:01   at com.evermind.server.ApplicationServer.setConfig(ApplicationServer.java:1049)
18/07/22 10:40:01   at com.evermind.server.ApplicationServerLauncher.run(ApplicationServerLauncher.java:131)
18/07/22 10:40:01   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:595)
18/07/22 10:40:01 Oracle Containers for J2EE 10g (10.1.3.3.0)  initialized
```

Below is the screenshot from OAF where the ports used are shown:

[OAF Ports Used](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1v4VL.png)

Also I am using Java 8 in my Windows 8.1 system.

Can Somebody help me please.

Regards,
Aayush

Answer (score 0):

Did you check that, used port is available ?
Please, open your console and write 
*netstat -aon*

Also Could you provide more information ?
Thank you.

Comment: Lord,I have added the screenshot in my question.